# Unable to get the state of logged in user in flutter-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

In my android app I am using firebase as a backend service.In my **main.dart** file I have Bottom navbar implemented and trying to get whether user is logged in or not but getting error like:

```
Error:Undefined class auth.currentUser
```

Below is my code please let me know what I am doing wrong and what i need to correct in below code.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart'; 
import './home.dart';
import './orders.dart';
import './account.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: MyTabs(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    primaryColorDark: Colors.grey,
    accentColor: Colors.green
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_MyTabsState createState() => _MyTabsState();
}

class _MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> {

   FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    if(auth.currentUser() == null){
        //Navigate to login page.
    }

int selectedIndex = 0;
final pages = [Home(),Orders(),Account()];

void choosePage(int index){

setState(() {

    selectedIndex = index;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text("Tiffino")
     ),
     body: pages[selectedIndex],
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      fixedColor: Colors.black,
      onTap: choosePage,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.home),
           title: Text("Home")
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.list),
           title: Text("Orders")
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: Text("Account")
         )
       ]
     )      
   );
  }
}
```

**THANKS**

Comment: Why you have defined `import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';` twice in your code on top .?

Comment: Oh sorry!  thanks for pointing it out actually I typed it double here but in actual code its imported one time only..

Comment: No Issues - I added an Answer to your Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the code -

```
if(auth.currentUser() == null){
  //Navigate to login page.
  }
```

in your `initState()` -

```
class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyTabsState createState() => _MyTabsState();
}

class _MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> {

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(auth.currentUser() == null){
      //Navigate to login page.
    }
  }

  .... // Code Cont
```

Comment: Updated the  answer to include more code. @Digvijay

Comment: Thanks bro, one thing I want to know why it was not working when it was not in init method.

Comment: `auth` is a State variable - initState() is just override method avail to State Object - you can run that Code in Any function defined by you. e.g - `void _getUser(){
    if(auth.currentUser() == null){
      //Navigate to login page.
    }
  }`